# Multi useRef for mapped array data with scroll to that ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My project is consist of books reading website, the text of each book is divided into a chunk of texts, here is example of book data from api endpoint:-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "bookContents": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "text": "This is is page 1 first content",
          "page": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
          "text": "This is is page 1 second content",
          "page": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
          "text": "This is is page 1 third content",
          "page": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 4,
          "text": "This is is page 2 first content",
          "page": 2
        },
        {
          "number": 5,
          "text": "This is is page 2 second content",
          "page": 2
        },
        {
          "number": 6,
          "text": "This is is page 3 first content",
          "page": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a feature where user can bookmark any text and then click on bookmark here, this is sample of how code looks like:-

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const BookRead = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const textRef = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost/api/getbook/253").then((res) => {
      setData(res.data.data);
      if (localStorage.getItem("bookmarkLocation")) {
        textRef[localStorage.getItem("bookmarkLocation")].scrollIntoView();
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.bookContents.map((content) => {
        <span
          ref={(ref) => textRef[content.number]}
          onClick={() =>
            localStorage.setItem("bookmarkLocation", content.number)
          }
        >
          {content.text}
        </span>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookRead;
```

The above code, not working it return scrollIntoView is not a function.

Comment: scrollIntoView can only be used with a DOM element and what you are storing into your local storge is not a DOM element.

Comment: @Aparna please provide alternate solution to above code, which can serve the same purpose